# ast python how to find connections between methods at different files

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to index all methods and thee connections between them in an entire application (A directory with sub directories and files eventually). I'm using `ast`, looping over directories till individual files and then loads them into an `ast` object like so `ast.parse(self.file_content)`

The index that i'm trying to create is this
[connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8EJx.png)

Here is my code, if it's relevant.

```
def scan(self):
    '''
        scans a file line by line while keeping context of location and classes
        indexes a file buffer content into a ast, Abstract Syntax Trees, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AST.
        Then, iterate over the elements, find relevant ones to index, and index them into the db.
    '''
    parsed_result = ast.parse(self.file_content)
    for element in parsed_result.body:
        results = self.index_element(element)


def index_element(self, element, class_name=None):
    '''

        if element is relevant, meaning method -> index
        if element is Class -> recursively call it self

    :param element:
    :param class_name:
    :return: [{insert_result: <db_insert_result>, 'structured_data': <method> object}, ...]
    '''
    # find classes
        # find methods inside classes
    # find hanging functions

    # validation on element type
    if self.should_index_element(element):
        if self.is_class_definition(element):
            class_element = element
            indexed_items = []
            for inner_element in class_element.body:
                # recursive call
                results = self.index_element(inner_element, class_name=class_element.name)
                indexed_items += results

            return indexed_items
        else:
            structured_data = self.structure_method_into_an_object(element, class_name=class_name)
            result_graph = self.dal_client.methods_graph.insert_or_update(structured_data)
            return "WhatEver"

    return "WhatEver"
```

My question is, is it possible to create this graph using `ast`. If yes, how?
From my understanding, I currently can't since I'm loading **one file at a time** to the `ast` object and it is *not aware of outside methods*.

here is an example for 2 files that I want to link between them:

`sample_a.py`

```
from sample_class_b import SampleClassB

sample_b = SampleClassB()

class SampleClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def test_call_to_another_function(self):
        return sample_b.test()
```

`sample_b.py`

```
class SampleClassB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 1

    def test(self):
        return True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse the `ast.Ast` tree and at each recursive call do one of four things:

1. If the tree is a `class` definition, store the `class` name with its associated methods, and then apply `Connections.walk` to each of the methods, storing the `class` and method name in the scope.
2. If the tree is an `import` statement, load the module and recursively run `Connections.walk` on it.
3. If an attribute lookup is being made and `Connections.walk` is within a method, check if the attribute name is a method of any `class`es currently loaded. If so, add an edge to `edges` that links the current scope with this new method discovered.
4. If none of the above occurs, continue to traverse the tree.

---

```
import ast, itertools
import re, importlib
class Connections:
   def __init__(self):
      self._classes, self.edges = {}, []
   def walk(self, tree, scope=None):
      t_obj = None
      if isinstance(tree, ast.ClassDef):
         self._classes[tree.name] = [i for i in tree.body if isinstance(i, ast.FunctionDef) and not re.findall('__[a-z]+__', i.name)]
         _ = [self.walk(i, [tree.name, i.name]) for i in self._classes[tree.name]]
         t_obj = [i for i in tree.body if i not in self._classes[tree.name]]
      elif isinstance(tree, (ast.Import, ast.ImportFrom)):
         for p in [tree.module] if hasattr(tree, 'module') else [i.name for i in tree.names]:
            with open(importlib.import_module(p).__file__) as f:
               t_obj = ast.parse(f.read())
      elif isinstance(tree, ast.Attribute) and scope is not None:
         if (c:=[a for a, b in self._classes.items() if any(i.name == tree.attr for i in b)]):
            self.edges.append((scope, [c[0], tree.attr]))
         t_obj = tree.value
      if isinstance(t_obj:=(tree if t_obj is None else t_obj), list):
         for i in t_obj:
            self.walk(i, scope = scope)
      else:
         for i in getattr(t_obj, '_fields', []):
            self.walk(getattr(t_obj, i), scope=scope)

with open('sample_a.py') as f:
   c = Connections()
   c.walk(ast.parse(f.read()))

print(c.edges)
```

Output:

```
[(['SampleClassA', 'test_call_to_another_function'], ['SampleClassB', 'test'])]
```

Important note: depending on the complexity of the files you are running `Connections.walk` on, a `RecursionError` might occur. To circumvent this, [here](https://gist.github.com/Ajax12345/82a3d5970db41f8335048ac02ae2b498) is a Gist that contains an iterative version of `Connections.walk`.

---

Creating a graph from `edges`:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g, labels, c1 = nx.DiGraph(), {}, itertools.count(1)
for m1, m2 in c.edges:
   if (p1:='.'.join(m1)) not in labels:
      labels[p1] = next(c1)
   if (p2:='.'.join(m2)) not in labels:
      labels[p2] = next(c1)
   g.add_node(labels[p1])
   g.add_node(labels[p2])
   g.add_edge(labels[p1], labels[p2])
   
nx.draw(g, pos, labels={b:a for a, b in labels.items()}, with_labels = True)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]